# Image Edit to see under a colour layer?

Tags: color, fonts, text

It is possible to take an existing image which has black texted covered by solid red layers and remove that so the text can be seen?

For instance this pictute here is a screenshot with black text covered by red colour layered over the top. It's for the purpose of some competitive branding pursuits etc.
[image]

Comment: Which software are you talking about? What exactly are you trying to achieve? (Including images is very helpful.) Please [edit] your question and add the missing info.

Comment: It's still pretty unclear. The way you describe what you want makes it difficult to understand. Do you mean you want to remove the red part of that image?

Comment: The image you have added doesn't show red *covering* the text, it shows a clear gap, implying the red is 'behind' the text [whether or not it's a separate layer or merely a visual representation]

Answer (score 1):

based upon -- *"black texted covered by solid red layers and remove that so the text can be seen"* -- Ill assume the use of the word "layers" here is referring to the apparent *visual* stacking of elements, not actual application-based layers like in Photoshop. Your "sample image" makes little sense because it clearly shows a red color with black text on top of it. There's nothing covered there at all. Except possibly the red area. So....

## No.

If the image is a flat file without any existing *actual* layers (like a jpg, png, gif, etc), all pixels have been **merged and flattened**. JPGs, PNGs, GIFs, et al do *not* have "layers" Everything is on the *same* pixel plane and there is no "stacking" of anything.

There is *nothing* behind the red area to "reveal" or see. Whatever *may* have been there when the image was created is removed when the pixels are merged and a non-layered image is saved, such as a jpg, png, gif, etc.

---

Television shows such as CSI have done a disservice by misinforming many. You can't *"remove that car from the photo so you can see the license plate behind it"*. Pixel-based formats don't have any layers and it is *impossible* to arbitrarily remove elements in order to see what you *think* should be behind that element.

Comment: Forensically, there is https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184099/secure-way-of-masking-out-sensitive-information-in-screenshots?noredirect=1&lq=1 & related links, but for your average user you nailed it.

Comment: However all bets are of if the image is a pdf

Comment: Well that's kind of a different situation. If the color overlay is applied *externally* to the base image, then yes it can possibly be removed, but if the color overlay is saved and embedded *as part of* the image, there will be no variations to detect `:)`

Comment: Not all bets @joojaa `:)` it merely depends if the overlay is added in the PDF over text or is part of an embedded image within the PDF `:)`

Comment: PDF covers a multitude of sins... & internal formats... some of which can reveal the sins ;)

Comment: @Scott not quite, the PDF can also include a old version of the page, a text excerpt of what used to be there etc. Its very easy to do all sorts of weird things with a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the blend mode of the red layers to multiply. Most editing programs can.

Or if you do not want to see red at all, turn off the layer or make it transparent.

Comment: I admire your spirit & determination... but I'm still waiting for the OP to tell us it's a jpg ;)

Comment: "black texted covered by solid red layers" That is... was the point before the edit and the image...

Comment: I know... but I work customer support for a living... what is said & what is meant often are separated by a large chasm of misplaced 'jargon'. ;)